# How to write a c code to detect the connection type using the function nm_connection_get_connection_type which is in the 'libnm' library

Tags: c, function, networking, shared-libraries, networkmanager

I want to write a c code which gives our system's connection type (whether it is ethernet or dongle) .I found one library 'libnm'(Network manager) and also i found one function nm_connection_get_connection_type inside that library. I don't know how to call that function in my code and I am confused is there any other function or method to detect the connection type.
Can any one help me by at least giving an idea about what to do?

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. It is lacking a lot of details.

Answer (score 1):

> How to write a c code to detect the connection type using the function nm_connection_get_connection_type which is in the 'libnm' library

Please read the C11 standard draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Look also into [this reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) about C, and read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/).

There is nothing in the specification of the C programming language which is related to networking.

### However, operating systems often provide libraries related to networking.

For Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and related pages. In particular see [sockets(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and [tcp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html). You might also be interested by [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

For Windows, dive inside the WinAPI documentation.

The `nm_connection_get_connection_type` function is documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMConnection.html). You certainly need to start reading about [Using libnm](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/usage.html). It returns a string that you might display, e.g. using `printf("current connection type %s\n", nm_connection_get_type(your_nm_connection))`. See of course [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Of course, you should also compile with all warnings and debug info (with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), that means [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program.

So read also the [documentation of GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) (and [of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/)).

On Linux, you could also use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to understand the behavior of yours (or some other's) program.

At last, the `libnm` library is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) (like all [GTK](https://gtk.org/)). **Consider downloading its source code and studying it.**

You probably use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to build your software. So read the documentation of GNU make. You might use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to edit your source code, so read its documentation.

Regarding shared libraries on Linux, read the [Program Library Howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) with [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) then Drepper's paper on [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) and the documentation of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).